# Problem with sms the activation code for the phone number

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, sms, activation

I use Flutter plugin to provide SMS code autofill support.
sms_autofill [The image shows that the device code has changed, and therefore the program does not respond to activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLMdt.jpg)

I tried to modify the programming code

The problem is that I cannot activate the phone number automatically by receiving the activation code
ى